# WPF Window does not load UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I guess I've got a pretty simple problem. I'm tying show a usercontrol via contentcontrol.
What a did is to create this usercontrol...

```
<UserControl x:Class="Exxeta.ModeldrivenCostEstimation.WPF.UserControlModelAnalysis"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="350" d:DesignWidth="525">
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="489" Margin="0,93,11,0" Height="164" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="489" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModelModelAnalysis.GridObjects}" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False">
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>


</Grid>
```

and declared the contentControl on my mainwindow

```
<Window x:Class="WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Test" Height="350" Width="525" ResizeMode="NoResize" Background="#FFE5E5E5">
    <ContentControl Name="Content"  Width="Auto" Opacity="1" Background="Transparent" ></ContentControl>
</Window>
```

.. And as I read I create the windows like this.

```
public MainWindow(***)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    model = new BasicViewModel();
    UserControl c1 = new UserControlModelAnalysis();
    this.Content = c1;
    this.DataContext = model;

}
```

But the content is not shown by the window. Did I missed something there ? 
Hope you can help me out of this little issue.

Thanks for your help
Iki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Whats happening is that the MainWindow.Content PUBLIC field is hiding the base classes Content property. You are setting the content field to your UserControl which is also a ContentControl hence no type cast error. Because The MainWindow.Content field is not a dependency property the UI is never updated and your content is not shown.

Answer: Rename your ContentControl and set the content property on the control.

This works.
Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Example_Project.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl x:Name="currentContent"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        currentContent.Content = new Content1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not initiate this from code behind although you can. Below is how you can use your control. The 'xmlns:local' definition add the local assembly and gives you access to the control.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:UserControl1></local:UserControl1>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

...

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock>Test</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: What I'm trying to build is something like an wizzard behavoir. Where I can click just to the next page. I've I should not initiate it from code behind . which is an easy why to build something like that

Comment: So want to exchange the content of control with new content?

Comment: What I have is my MainWindows which is a normal WPF Window. I also declared a contentcontrol on it. I declared also a few usercontrol with different ui elements. If I start the WPF the window the first usercontrol should be shown. On a "Next" Click the secound usercontrol should be shown and so on.. I want that it looks like a normals wizzard..

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved from code behind like below. You could have your usercontrols in there like I add the buttons to the content.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl x:Name="Content"></ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private Button m_Button1;
        private Button m_Button2;

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Loaded -= MainWindow_Loaded;

            m_Button1 = new Button { Content = "Button1" };
            m_Button2 = new Button { Content = "Button2" };

            m_Button1.Click += button1_Click;
            m_Button2.Click += m_Button2_Click;

            Content.Content = m_Button1;
        }

        void m_Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Content.Content = m_Button1;
        }

        void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Content.Content = m_Button2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you for your respones. Its running now. What I basicly did is to drag and drop one of my UserControles onto the Window and load the next one like 
this.currentContent.Content = new Content1().. like I already did..and it works. I guess that what kicks said explained my problem right :-) 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that the Loaded event was not raised when I tried to show it in the constructor. This is not a good idea.

```
public partial class MyDockpaneView : UserControl
    {
        public MyDockpaneView ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MyDockpaneView _Loaded;
            MyDockpaneViewModel.Show();
        }
```

MyDockpaneView _Loaded() is not called unless comment out MyDockpaneView.Show();